# IsDate function in data validation vba

Tags: vba, validation

I would like to do data validation for specific column,

I able to restrict user to input numeric and text by
doing:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

    Select Case rng
        Case "Text"
            valFormulaText = "=istext(" & Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(65535, 0)).Address(False, False) & ")"
            Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(65535, 0)).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=valFormulaText
        Case "Numeric"
            valFormulaNumeric = "=isnumber(" & Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(65535, 0)).Address(False, False) & ")"
            Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(65535, 0)).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=valFormulaNumeric
        Case "Date"
            varFormulaDate = "=isdate(" & Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(65535, 0)).Address(False, False) & ")"
            Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(65535, 0)).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=varFormulaDate
    End Select

End Sub
```

While there is error for the Date case with runtime error 1004'

Answer (score 1):

There are function isnumber() and istext() in Excel. But isdate() isn't. You should add the function for isdate before using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
varFormulaDate = "=isdate" & ...
```

Missing "(" after `isdate`

Comment: it seems it still have error for the function =isdate()